# AngularJS Directives with Circular Dependency

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a circular directive dependency situation.

```
DirectiveA.template = '<div switch-on="v"> <DirectiveB when="someVal" /> </div>';
DirectiveB.template = '<div> <DirectiveA /> </div>';
```

What this will do, if you set up this situation, is hang Chrome and eventually crash the page.

I think the reason is because the way the $compile works it will cause endless recursion.

However, as you can see based on my switch statement, there is a recursion terminator clause.  As soon as "someVal" is not equal to $scope.v it should end the recursion.

So my question: is there any way to setup a circular dependency between 2 directives?

Comment: create a demo with a simple use case that shows what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because as I mentioned it will crash the browser.  Just for kicks I tried it in plnkr and then it crashed on me and I lost my work lol.  Do I really need to go into more detail?  Is anyone actually confused about what my question is asking?

Comment: post more code then with a better explanation of what you want it to do. Hard to help with what little info is given. Can always comment out the part that causes crash in demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, this is similar to recursive directives.  As you have learned, Angular will spin forever.  This is because of the way the `$compile` and `link` functions work in Angular.  To fix it, you need to conditionally compile the circular reference.  Here is an [example assuming recursion](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/), but the approach is very similar.

Basically, you need to extract your conditional logic from the template into the `link` function of your directive.  In your case, the conditional that will eventually result in the termination of the circluar reference is in `DirectiveA`.  It would look something like this (untested, because I don't have a full example of your code):

```
app.directive('DirectiveA', function ($compile) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      if(scope.v === "circular_condition") {
        element.append('<DirectiveB when="someVal" />');
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The actual solution might be more complex if `scope.v` will ever change.  You will have to `$watch` the `v` property and add/remove the `DirectiveB` based on the value of `v`.  But that gets into the realm of more normal Angular stuff, so I won't muddy the response with that.

Comment: This was all I needed to know.